# Gradle in Spring Boot project not recognizing Java jdk in Path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradlew

I have a spring boot application where the gradle version is 7.0.

I had to change my openjdk 16 to openjdk 11 because I want to use keycloak with the project.
After I updated the Path, my java 11 gets recognized:

[image]

But my gradle is still stuck on the other version:

[image]

Edit: I have noticed that the error is in my build.gradle file:
[image]

Things I have tried:

- restarting my pc
- deleting cache folders for vscode
- putting a JAVA_HOME into my path and link it and reverted it(I checked everytime with a new powershell window to make sure that it has updated and it always worked)
- test another spring project (The other spring boot app does not have this gradle issue)

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Open the gradlew bat file and echo JAVA_HOME   every time you see it's being tried to be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I would look closely at the other spring boot app that does not have this gradle issue.  VSCode has a habit of keeping cached versions of files around, but really you want the gradle files to be interrupted so it downloads new dependencies.  I would look into that next, if you can't figure out what makes your other project work and this one not.